# Python - Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: python, dijkstra

I need to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm in Python. However, I have to use a 2D array to hold three pieces of information - predecessor, length and unvisited/visited.
I know in C a Struct can be used, though I am stuck on how I can do a similar thing in Python, I am told it's possible but I have no idea to be honest

Comment: Maybe it would help to actually learn Python? Like basic data structures and such? But I guess you don't have time for that...

Comment: I have done a little bit of Python before, though I have never come across what I feel is a 'complex' situation like this in regards to data structures, so I thank you all for your answers

Comment: Does it *need* to be represented in a C-style, compact 2D array? If it can be done with objects, you can use classes and Python's builtin data structures so that the language will fit more properly with the problem domain. Otherwise, some hack-ish retrofitting with C-style structures would be inevitable. Not pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use an instance of an object.

This author has a pretty convincing python implementation of Dijkstras in python.

```
#
# This file contains the Python code from Program 16.16 of
# "Data Structures and Algorithms
# with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Python"
# by Bruno R. Preiss.
#
# Copyright (c) 2003 by Bruno R. Preiss, P.Eng.  All rights reserved.
#
# http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/programs/pgm16_16.txt
#
class Algorithms(object):

    def DijkstrasAlgorithm(g, s):
        n = g.numberOfVertices
        table = Array(n)
        for v in xrange(n):
            table[v] = Algorithms.Entry()
        table[s].distance = 0
        queue = BinaryHeap(g.numberOfEdges)
        queue.enqueue(Association(0, g[s]))
        while not queue.isEmpty:
            assoc = queue.dequeueMin()
            v0 = assoc.value
            if not table[v0.number].known:
                table[v0.number].known = True
                for e in v0.emanatingEdges:
                    v1 = e.mateOf(v0)
                    d = table[v0.number].distance + e.weight
                    if table[v1.number].distance > d:

                        table[v1.number].distance = d
                        table[v1.number].predecessor = v0.number
                        queue.enqueue(Association(d, v1))
        result = DigraphAsLists(n)
        for v in xrange(n):
            result.addVertex(v, table[v].distance)
        for v in xrange(n):
            if v != s:
                result.addEdge(v, table[v].predecessor)
        return result
    DijkstrasAlgorithm = staticmethod(DijkstrasAlgorithm)
```

Notice those pieces of information are 'held' in the object he is constructing by calling Algorithms.Entry().  Entry is a class and is defined like this:

```
class Entry(object):
    """
    Data structure used in Dijkstra's and Prim's algorithms.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        (Algorithms.Entry) -> None
        Constructor.
        """
        self.known = False
        self.distance = sys.maxint
        self.predecessor = sys.maxint
```

The self.known, self.distance... are those pieces of information. He does not set these explicit in the constructor (**init**) but sets them later. In Python you can access attributes with dot notation. for examle: myObject= Entry().  the myObject.known, myObject.distance... they are all public.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class for it.

```
class XXX(object):
    def __init__(self, predecessor, length, visited):
        self.predecessor = predecessor
        self.length = length
        self.visited = visited
```

Or use collections.namedtuple, which is particular cool for holding struct-like compound types without own behaviour but named members: `XXX = collections.namedtuple('XXX', 'predecessor length visited')`.

Create one with `XXX(predecessor, length, visited)`.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate that information in a Python object and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use tuples or dictionaries inside your 2d array:

```
width=10
height=10

my2darray = []
for x in range(width):
   my2darray[x]=[]

for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):
      #here you set the tuple
      my2darray[x][y] = (n,l,v) 
      #or you can use a dict..
      my2darray[x][y] = dict(node=foo,length=12,visited=False)
```

Comment: As syntax highlighting indicates, identifiers can't start with numbers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Python is object oriented language. So think of it like moving from Structs in C to Classes of C++. You can use the same class structure in Python as well.